# Property setter with multiple values

Tags: python, setter

I have a property setter which generates a unique id by taking two strings and hashing it:

```
@id.setter
def id(self,value1,value2):
    self._id = sha512(value1+value2)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it allowed (considering good python coding practices) to code this way
2. How do I pass two values to the setter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How do I pass two values to the setter?

You can pass an iterable(tuple, list) to the setter, for example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.idx = val

    @property    
    def idx(self):
        return self._idx

    @idx.setter
    def idx(self, val):
        try:
            value1, value2 = val
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Pass an iterable with two items")
        else:
            """ This will run only if no exception was raised """
            self._idx = sha512(value1+value2)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = A(['foo', 'bar'])     #pass a list
>>> b = A(('spam', 'eggs'))   #pass a tuple
>>> a.idx
<sha512 HASH object @ 0xa57e688>
>>> a.idx = ('python', 'org')  #works
>>> b.idx = ('python',)         #fails
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    raise ValueError("Pass an iterable with two items")
ValueError: Pass an iterable with two items
```

Answer (score 8):

The setter can only take one value, so use a tuple: `(value1, value2)`.

```
@id.setter
def id(self,value):          
    self._id = sha512(str(value))

...

self.id = (value1, value2)
```

(You didn't post what `sha512` is. I'm assuming you are using `hashlib.sha512`, and `sha512` is calling the `update` method, which requires a string as input.)

Answer (score 5):

I have some doubts regarding the coding practices here. As a user of an API, I'd always assume that whatever I set as a property, I can get it back from the same property. In addition to that, having something called `id` mutable looks suspicious.

As for passing two values, how about:

```
@id.setter
def id(self, vals):
    value1, value2 = vals
    self._id = sha512(value1+value2)
```

Then assign a tuple:

```
myobj.id = (val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's what you want, but here is an other way for passing two values or more:

```
@idx.setter
def idx(self, args):
    self._idx = sha512(''.join([str(i) for i in args]))
```

You can avoid the restriction of list or tuple :

```
a.idx = 'zere', 'fezfz'
a.idx = ("eddez", "erez")
a.idx = 'deze', 'drezre', 'ezre'
```

You have to test for exception and handle excpetion in init.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [property()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) function as well like this.

```
from hashlib import sha512

class U:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.id_setter(value1, value2)

    def id_getter(self):
        return self._id

    def id_setter(self, value1: str, value2: str):
    value1, value2 = value1.encode(), value2.encode()
    self._id = sha512(value1+value2)

    id = property(id_getter, id_setter) # <----

u = U("Foo", "Bar")
print(u.id.hexdigest())
```