# Python: can I unpack arguments without calling a function?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

I have `dict` that I want to convert to several different objects.  For instance:

#### Currently Have

```py
kwargs = {'this': 7, 'that': 'butterfly'}
```

---

And I want to convert it, maybe using something similar to function argument unpacking, but without actually calling a function, so that I end up with something like:

#### Desired

```py
**kwargs
print(this) # Will print out `7`
print(that) # Will print out `'butterfly'`
```

I know that I cannot use the double-star [`**`] bare like I have shown.  But is there something similar I can do?

---

## Edit: More Specifics

Since folks were asking for details and warning that what I am trying to do is dangerous, I will give more context for my need.

I have a *property* in a class that I want to set using keyword arguments.  Something like what is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714518/534238), but unpacking `kwargs` instead of `args`.

As a functioning toy example, it looks like this:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._idx = None
    @property
    def idx(self):
        return self._idx
    @idx.setter
    def idx(self, kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self._idx = {}
        for kw, val in kwargs.items():
            self._idx[kw] = val
```

This works. But now I am unit testing the function, and in the unit test, I would like to be able to provide the specific key-value pairs as normal objects, so that I can effectively use `hypothesis` and `pytest`'s `@mark.parametrize` effectively.

In order to do this, it looks like I will need the "bare unpacking" like I described above.

Since these are all actually local variables within a method, I feel like @g.d.d.c's concerns are probably not significant.  It sounds like his worries were if I created new global variables without knowing what they were.

Comment: Can you provide the test you want to write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: this approach is *dangerous*.  You should not (in most circumstances) muddle with `locals()` or `globals()`.  However, what you want can be done, kind of:

```
>>> kwargs = {'this': 7, 'that': 'butterfly'}
>>> 
>>> locals().update(kwargs)
>>> this
7
>>> that
'butterfly'
```

It still calls a function (the update on `locals()`) but it does give you names in your local namespace.

Comment: Hi @g.d.d.c, I updated the question to address your concerns.  Knowing that all the "action" is happening inside a class method, do you still feel this is dangerous?  There is no cluttering of the global namespace.

Comment: It is absolutely still dangerous. Doc reference:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals.  Just because it's possible doesn't mean you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```py
this, that = {"this": 7, "that": "butterfly"}.values()
```

But it is really specific. The question would be why do you have the values in a dict in the first place.

You seem to have them in kwargs, why cannot you expend them there?

If you don't know the keys in the dict how can you then use them in the code?

If you know the keys in the dict, why not simply expand it like so:

```py
this, that = kwargs["this"], kwargs["that"]
```

And my final question? Why not use `kwargs["this"]` where you need the variable, especially if you don't need it a lot.

Can you provide us with the real use case so that we can tell you how we would do that?

Comment: Hi @Natim, I provided more details.  Regardless, I needed unpacking in a non-hard coded manner, so this would not work.

As I said to g.d.d.c., I will find another way to handle it.